# Why matrix multiplication with -O3 flag takes longer than -O0 in C?

Tags: c, matrix, optimization, caching

I was trying to multiply two matrices with different techniques to understand the usage of caches and I encountered some interesting results that I don't know what is happening.

If I try to multiply two matrices with row-column multiplication (A[i][j] = B[i][k] * C[k][j]) it tooks about 28sec without any optimization flags, but if I run the same code with -O3 flag, it tooks about 40sec for the same 1024x1024 matrices.

```
int** mulMatrices(int **matrix1, int **matrix2) {
    int **resultM = malloc(sizeof(int*) * ROWS);
    resultM[0] = malloc(sizeof(int) * ROWS * COLS);
    for(int i = 1; i < ROWS; i++) {
        resultM[i] = resultM[i - 1] + COLS;
    }
    memset(resultM[0], 0, sizeof(int) * ROWS * COLS);

    clock_t start, end;
    double cpu_time_used;
    start = clock();

    for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            for(int k = 0; k < COLS; k++) {
                resultM[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j]; 
            }
        }
    }

    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((double)(end - start)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
    printf("without row-wise mul: %f\n", cpu_time_used);

    return resultM;
}
```

but if I do the same things with below matrix multiplication, it tooks about 25sec without optimization flags and 1.5sec with -O3 as expected since I believe it uses caches more efficient.

```
int** mulMat(int **matrix1, int **matrix2) {
    int **resultM = malloc(sizeof(int*) * ROWS);
    resultM[0] = malloc(sizeof(int) * ROWS * COLS);
    for(int i = 1; i < ROWS; i++) {
        resultM[i] = resultM[i - 1] + COLS;
    }
    memset(resultM[0], 0, sizeof(int) * ROWS * COLS);

    clock_t start,end;
    double cpu_time_used;

    start = clock();

    for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            for(int k = 0; k < COLS; k++) {
                resultM[i][k] += matrix1[i][j] * matrix2[j][k];
            }
        }
    }

    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((double)(end - start)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
    printf("with row-wise mul: %f\n", cpu_time_used);

    return resultM;
}
```

My question is, why it takes longer for normal matrix multiplication with -O3 than with -O0?
Thanks.

Comment: `int ij = 0` is unused so the only relevant diff is the inner resultM line.  Next time present one program and use a macro to toggle between the two versions.

Comment: @AllanWind, I forgot to delete this line while editing,

Comment: Your question is about the first version so I don't think your optimized 2nd version is really relevant, right?

Comment: What a bizarre way to allocate space for your matrix.  It looks like it would work, but if you're going to allocate it all in one block, then why manually de-optimize by presenting an array-of-pointers facade on top?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I was trying to get rid of the cost of malloc and free calls but I wasn't aware that I was de-optimizing it, what would be a better allocation? thanks.

Comment: @AllanWind, yes my question was about the first version.

Comment: I don't know how we can answer this, btw, without data, compiler and probably platform.   If you are on linux perf should tell you you what is going on with your cache utilization.  I tried compiling both versions with -S to see the assembler versions which are quite different.  Not something I usually dabble in.

Comment: @yusfux, use type `int (*matrix)[COLS]`, and allocate as (only) `matrix = malloc(ROWS * sizeof(*matrix))`.  Or allocate + initialize with (only) `matrix = calloc(ROWS, sizeof(*matrix))`.

Comment: What @JohnBollinger can also be made into a `typedef`  to simplify coding: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/qaPjsqxYn)

Comment: `resultM[i] = resultM[i - 1] + COLS;` is not correct unless `sizeof(int*) == sizeof(int)`. This is not true in 64-bit systems.

Comment: Nevertheless, I do not reproduce your observation with GCC 8.5.0.  I wrote a `main()` that allocates two 1024x1024 matrices using the same approach demonstrated by the two examples in the question, fills them with random elements, and performs the matrix multiplication using the first code (verbatim).  I saw a more than a 3x improvement in the time reported by the given function when the result was compiled with `gcc -O3` *vs* when it was compiled with `gcc -O0`.

Comment: I also got an improvement in each case from changing the data representation as I previously described -- about 20% faster with `-O0`, but a whopping 86% faster with `-O3` (on top of the improvement from `-O3` *vs* `-O0`).  Overall, the data structure change plus `-O3` gives me a run time of a mere 4% of the time required for the `-O0` version with the original data structure.

Comment: You don't show the values for `ROWS` and `COLS`, but unless `ROWS == COLS`, you don't have compatible (multipliable) matrices.  If you have a matrix `M1[R1][C1]` and another `M2[R2][C2]`, then `M1 * M2` (in that order) requires `C1 == R2` and the result is `M3[R1][C2]`.  If the matrices are square, so `R1 == R2 && R1  == C1 && R1 == C2`, then you're OK.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, Now I was checking the "perf" stats for the -O3 and -O0 flags thanks to Allan Wind's advice, I realized that both -O3 and -O0 optimizations runs with %33 miss rate but with the different number of instructions and surprisingly I got the same results for both of them (44sec for 2048x2048).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I was just checking for square matrices thanks for your warning.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, thanks for your time, I will try to understand what is going on in the light of your advices and I will report the results, thanks again to everyone.

Comment: The absolute timing *vs* my absolute times, plus a basic analysis of the dimensions of the test as you present it, lead me to wonder whether your performance measurements reflect the cost of paging out some of your data to disk.  Just the matrix elements themselves probably take 4GB per matrix at 1024 x 1024 x sizeof(int), and you need at least three of those.  The costs of such paging would be likely to dominate the overall time consumed.